# Overriding Title Double Click

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to override what happens when you double-click on the Title Bar in my WPF Application. I have tried to look into this and I want to keep it as simple as possible since it is a small program and would prefer not to include any libraries. The idea is that I would like to double-click on the Title Bar and the contents of the window will become hidden or visible if it is hidden. I have sample application that actually changes a few things such as drawing the Title Bar from within WPF. But I can't figure this out, any help would greatly be appreciated!

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=Titlebar}"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Border Background="DarkGray" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" x:Name="Titlebar">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window},FallbackValue=Title}" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="White" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </TextBlock.Effect>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4" x:Name="Content">
            <TextBlock Text="Window content" x:Name="Text"/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: What currently happens when you double click on it?  It looks like your `Window` doesn't have a *real* title bar, just a `Border` with a `TextBlock` inside of it.  If you want to have something happen when you double click on the `Border` or the `TextBlock`, you should be able to add an event handler for that event.

Comment: I apologize, if I try and add any event to the "Titlebar" Border or any of it's children it does not fire at all. I am confused on how to get this to work. So if I did `<Border Background="DarkGray" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" x:Name="Titlebar" MouseDown="Titlebar_MouseDown">` it will not call the `Titlebar_MouseDown` method.

Comment: This isn't exposed in WPF directly, you have to intercept the WM_NCLDOUBLECLICK notification that Windows generates.  HwndSourceHook.AddHook() required.  It isn't exposed because nobody ever expects it to work differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, thanks to Hans Passant I did some digging around to what he mentioned and figured this out. You need to add the following to your source code.

```
private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3;

protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

This should only fire on a double click in the No Client Area, but as he mentioned it isn't exposed normally since nobody expects the double-click on the title bar to do something different. I only wanted it because I needed an easy way to hide the contents of a window and collapse it to just the Title Bar since you can't actually resize my window.

Comment: Thank you so much for this question. Shows some Research and very useful